# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, slf4j

some problems with java and slf4j
Made project using idea and it is ok. But in case I try to make jar with gradle I have some problems.

build.gradle

```
group 'test.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.20'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'

}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Test'
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("info");
    }
}
```

Terminal:

```
gradle build
java -jar target/HttpServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at HttpServerHH.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I tried to use gradle/maven (mvn package) the same problem. Some reasons it cannot find Logger and LoggerFactory in classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Michael for remembering about fat jar. After your comment tried to google: "gradle build fat jar" and after it modified my build.gradle

```
jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Test'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JVM cannot find dependencies on classpath because they're not on classpath obviously. By default Gradle and Maven add just your classes to a jar and you have to specify paths to the dependencies manually with the `-cp` argument. If you want to build a fat jar you can use [ShadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) with Gradle and [Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) with Maven.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.6'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.6'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.18'
}
```

Comment: logback-core was missing. As per my understanding. Also refresh dependency right click on project ->Gradle->refresh Dependency. It should work for you