# Gradle IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar, executable-jar

when i add slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar and slf4j-nop-1.6.4.jar in my libs folder it works fine but if i replaced them with gradle dependency then while executing the jar it gives me below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

these are gradle dependencies for my project for above libraries.

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.6.4'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-nop', version: '1.6.4'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XUGGLE ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434862/xuggle-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-slf)

Comment: @user629735 but why its not working when i compile from gradle instead of lib class path

Comment: What folder is it you talk about when you say "my libs folder" and how do you execute the JAR?

Comment: Hm the neeed jar files must be downloaded . To do so make sure you run Grandle Build . So in your classpath you have to see a folder named `Artifacts and Depencities` or something like that and inside it needs to have the jar files . Also do a fresh clean in your project .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've run Gradle Build, it may not have pulled your dependencies.

Comment: i have double check with that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include these dependencies in the jar file (like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/)).